# Make excel data csv compatible

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want the excel data to be stored in CSV form with quotes around the number. When I used this `=""""&B2&""""` to get the quote, I got 3 quotes around the number.

[image]

What I acually want is this:
[image]

How can I get only a single quote as below for the whole row using excel formula and saving it as csv.

Comment: You normally have no reason to process quotes at Excel level: if required, they are added (resp. removed) when saving into (resp. loading from) a csv file.

Comment: I want to add quotes for csv file. I am preparing my own dataset so I want the whole column to have a quote. But, when opened in csv I am getting three quotes but I want only a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely normal. Quote are intended to quote special characters **including themselves**. So quotes are doubled inside a quoted field. When you see 3 quotes (`"""2"""`) in the csv file, the outermost quotes are the normal quotes around a field, and the inner quotes are normally doubled quotes inside a quoted field.

Any *normal* csv parser will:

- remove the outermost quotes
- replace any doubled quote (`""`) inside the field with a single one(`"`) giving back as expected `"2"`